# Cannot install Parsivar normalizer on Google Colab

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

When I want to install Parsivar normalizer on Google Colab, I get this error.
This is my installation code:
I use pip to install Parsivar normalizer. This error occurs for about two weeks. before that time I didn't have any problem to install Parsivar.

```
!pip install parsivar
from parsivar import Normalizer
my_normalizer = Normalizer()
```

And this is my error's call stack.

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-a4ae8568f137> in <cell line: 2>()
      1 get_ipython().system('pip install parsivar')
----> 2 from parsivar import Normalizer
      3 my_normalizer = Normalizer()

7 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/parsivar/__init__.py in <module>
----> 1 from .chunker import FindChunks
      2 from .data_helper import DataHelper
      3 from .dependency import DependencyParser
      4 from .normalizer import Normalizer
      5 from .postagger import POSTagger

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/parsivar/chunker.py in <module>
----> 1 import nltk
      2 
      3 class FindChunks():
      4     def __init__(self):
      5         self.grammar = r"""

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/nltk/__init__.py in <module>
    132 from nltk.grammar import *
    133 from nltk.probability import *
--> 134 from nltk.text import *
    135 from nltk.tree import *
    136 from nltk.util import *

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/nltk/text.py in <module>
     24 from six import text_type
     25 
---> 26 from nltk.lm import MLE
     27 from nltk.lm.preprocessing import padded_everygram_pipeline
     28 from nltk.probability import FreqDist

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/nltk/lm/__init__.py in <module>
    220 """
    221 
--> 222 from nltk.lm.models import (
    223     MLE,
    224     Lidstone,

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/nltk/lm/models.py in <module>
     10 
     11 from nltk import compat
---> 12 from nltk.lm.api import LanguageModel, Smoothing
     13 from nltk.lm.smoothing import KneserNey, WittenBell
     14 

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/nltk/lm/api.py in <module>
     15 from six import add_metaclass
     16 
---> 17 from nltk.lm.counter import NgramCounter
     18 from nltk.lm.util import log_base2
     19 from nltk.lm.vocabulary import Vocabulary

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/nltk/lm/counter.py in <module>
     13 from __future__ import unicode_literals
     14 
---> 15 from collections import Sequence, defaultdict
     16 
     17 from six import string_types

ImportError: cannot import name 'Sequence' from 'collections' (/usr/lib/python3.10/collections/__init__.py)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Could anyone help?
Thanks.

Comment: The error you encountered seems to be related to the import of the Sequence class from the collections module. This issue can occur if you're using Python 3.10, as the Sequence class was removed from the collections module in Python 3.10.

One possible solution is to downgrade your Python version to a version prior to 3.10 in order to resolve the compatibility issue. You can do this in Google Colab by executing the following command: `!pip install python==3.9`

Answer (score 1):

For install parsivar on Google Colab we can use this steps :

1.Install the parsivar by command below :

```
!pip install parsivar
```

2.Then we need to install parsivar normalizer model by command below :

```
!wget https://github.com/ICTRC/Parsivar/archive/refs/heads/master.zip
!unzip master.zip
```

3.After downloading and extracting the files, navigate to the "Parsivar-master/Normalizer" directory. You can do this by running the following command:

```
%cd Parsivar-master/Normalizer
```

4.In the last step we can use `setup.py` to install normalize parsivar on Google Colab, to run this file follow the command below :

```
!python setup.py install
```